# Slashing/Validator reward /Treasury Reward in NEAR

Tags: nearprotocol, nearprotocol-validator

I want to capture all the balance changing operations for any near address provided.

I have got the info of all the action types and archival apis to pull out the transactions. Can any one help with the apis to get the slashing and reward distribution apis. Rewards again are distributed to the validator and some part goes to treasury.

Please help me with the blocks and apis using which I can validate the theoretical concept so that i can capture all the balance changing operations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have already collect this information [here](https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-explorer#shared-public-access), there is a read-only access to the DB. You need `account_changes` table.

Rewards are marked with `account_changes.update_reason = 'VALIDATOR_ACCOUNTS_UPDATE'`.

Slashing is turned off for now, so you will not see anything about it.